# Apple Configurator for iOS not detected on Macbook Pro 2020 M1 during Enrollment

Tags: ios, apple-configurator

Currently trying to enroll a new MacBook Pro using the apple configuration app. Following the guide here https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/apple-configurator/welcome/ios but stuck on scanning the orb part.

On the Select country/region page brought the app on the iphone closer but to no avail

[image: Scanning orb]

The configurator app is installed on my iphone XR. Bringing the my phone with the configurator app open close to the new macbook didnt detect it.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mac must run macOS Monterey or newer for the apple configurator to work.